# add selected row from a table to another table and then be able to undo it so it goes back to its before table with Jquery and MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3, EF Model first on my project.

I have a view with 5 tables and then I have a CustomPickedTable, whenever a user click on a row inside those 4 tables that row moves to CUstomPickedTable this is the code for it:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {       
        $(".questionsForSubjectType tbody tr").click(function () {
            $(this).appendTo("#CustomPickedTable tbody");

       });

        });
   </script>
```

What I want that users also should be able to do is to click on a row inside the CustomPickedTable and then the choosen row goes back to where it was before. Some kind of undo function.

All 4 tables have same class and unique ID.

How can I do this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.questionsForSubjectType tbody tr').click(function () {
            var origin = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
            var index = $(this).index();
            $(this)
                .appendTo('#CustomPickedTable tbody')
                .click({ origin: origin, index: index }, function (evt) {
                    $('#' + evt.data.origin + ' tbody tr')
                        .eq(evt.data.index - 1)
                        .after(this);
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Trying to put it back at the same index is probably asking for trouble, as other items may also have been moved from that table.  Otherwise solution looks good.

Comment: @Betty, yes, that's correct. It will be trouble in this case. Otherwise we could ignore the index when reappending back and simply insert the row either at the end or at the beginning.

Comment: I tried to apply your code, when I click on a row from one of the 4 tables it moves to another table like its suppose to :) But when I click on a row inside CustomPickedTable nothing happens :S

Comment: Have you verified if the second .click callback is fired? Also as pointed out by Betty you could ignore the index as it might cause problems.

Comment: Can it because of my ids on my tables? Im using foreachs and my id gets generated like this " id="questionsForSubjectType_@(questionsGroupedBySubjectType.SubjectTypeId)" which results in questionsForSubjectType_7 etc

Comment: Hmm, that's very weird as I have tested the code and it worked fine for me. Here's a live demo by the way: http://jsfiddle.net/MsNJ8/1/

Comment: Oh! My tables do not have ID its a div tag that gets it an ID, .questionsForSubjectType is a div class aswell

Comment: Well then adapt the selectors.

Comment: I guess its .closest('table') I need to change to 'div' but its still not working :S How can I adapt it?

Comment: I don't know how your markup looks like so I cannot really help you any further. Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net example with your code.

Comment: @RammtinAvar, you have broken HTML. You have 2 div elements with the same id="questionsForSubjectType_7". That's not possible.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Ops I copy pasted the other table its suppose to have different ID sorry. Updated http://jsfiddle.net/VpC8r/2/

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It's not working but I might know why, inside each div I have 4 Tables.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Many thanks Darin, I solved it by using the generated unique ID on my tables instead of the div tag. Only problem right now is to reset the DOM when you click on "Back" Button :)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It gets trouble when I have more then one value in a Table when I want to undo and remove my question from CustomPickedTable. It duplicates to its ordinary table when I remove it. :S